# Show content if class exists

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to show content from a div if the class `active` exists on a button.

```
<button type="button" class="tab tab-library">Library</button>
<button type="button" class="tab tab-home active">Home</button>
<button type="button" class="tab tab-settings">Settings</button>
```

These are the buttons I have, and the toggling of the `active` class works depending on the button pressed.

However I'm struggling with showing different content when I press any particular button.

```
<div class="home-container">
   <div class="home">

      Content

   </div>
</div>
```

Only the container that has the `active` class should be visible/displayed.

No jQuery please as I'm still trying to learn plain JS.

Comment: You need to show your JS attempt.

Comment: If there's always exactly one active button, save the reference to the active button in a variable. Then when a new button is made active, remove the active class from the saved reference and overwrite that reference to the new active button.

Answer (score 0):

this is test code, you can use **querySelector** , if class exit then alert ok or not, for test click the **click** button then alert will **ok**

```js
function test() {
        if (document.querySelector('.home') !== null) {
            alert('ok');
        } else {
            alert('not');
        }
    }
```

```html
<body>
<div class="home-container">
    <div class="home">

        Content

    </div>
    <span style="cursor: pointer; background: #0f192a;color: #00BD9B" onclick="test()">Click</span>
</div>
</body>
```